# Jenkins blueocean plugin - Unable to create pipeline from github

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-blueocean

Getting below error in Jenkins during the last step of creating pipeline from github using personal access token -

```
Sep 03, 2017 7:34:43 AM com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform$JdkWithJettyBootPlatform getSelectedProtocol
INFO: ALPN callback dropped: SPDY and HTTP/2 are disabled. Is alpn-boot on the boot class path?
```

- Jenkins ver. 2.78
- openjdk version "1.8.0_141"

I am running jenkins using vagrant inside CentOS 7.

Comment: Jenkins blueocean is unable to create pipeline & push changes to github.

Comment: As you've posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169459/jenkins-blueocean-plugin-pipeline-editor-unable-to-open-jenkinsfile), I assume this works now? How did you solve it?

Comment: No. I haven't got any solution as if now.

Comment: Pipeline works using just plain git instead of github but i can't edit it using pipeline editor.

Answer (score 1):

It worked fine after changing my machine from Mac OS to Ubuntu & upgrading the blueocean plugin to "1.3.0-beta-2".

The reason could be proxy or some other setting which was not allowing the communication to happen.

Since it took fair amount to time to debug, I hope someone else doesn't waste their time & check their machine configs before putting a bug.