# Pipeline editor unable to open Jenkinsfile in Jenkins BlueOcean

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I am extremely new to BlueOcean and am getting the below error when trying to open the pipeline editor:

> There was an error loading the pipeline from the Jenkinsfile in this
>    repository. Correct the error by editing the Jenkinsfile using the
>   declarative syntax then commit it back to the repository.
>
> Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

**Jenkinsfile**:

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Build') {
        steps {
            echo 'Building..'
        }
    }
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            echo 'Testing..'
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        steps {
            echo 'Deploying....'
        }
     }
  }
}
```

**Error screenshot -**

[image: ERROR]

Comment: Looks like a bug, please report it in the Jenkins issue tracker.

Comment: Filed a bug - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46806 .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is probably a bug in the software or a not yet implemented feature missing.

Comment: I think this is a bug since the same thing is done by pipeline editor, it changes the Jenkinsfile & pushes it to the repo. If we have a compatible Jenkinsfile in our repo, it should support it. Waiting to hear a response on the Jenkins JIRA.

Comment: It sounds like this may be related to a bug (support of proxy server configuration) so yeah, this is likely best answered by the linked support ticket